# Change user folder name in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I recently upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. During setting up process I had entered my Microsoft Email address. Now the folder in C:\Users is C:\Users\reese . It took the first 5 characters from my email address.

How should I change the name to C:\Users\John Reese ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 : Go to Settings → Family and other people → Add someone to this PC → I don't have this person's sign-in information → Add a user without Microsoft Account → Fill in the details

Step 2 : Go to Control Panel → User Accounts → User Accounts → Manage another account → Now make the new account Administrator(Important step)

Step 3 : Sign out and then login into the new account.

Step 4 : Delete the old account from Control Panel → User Accounts → User Accounts → Manage another account (Optional)

Comment: dang, is this seriously the only way?

For me it's set my user folder as georg, because my usual name is too long for the auto-generated folder.

Comment: This is the easiest way or one of the other ways is to reinstall and not enter outlook email address at all in the installation process.

Comment: this way everything that is installed in the other user directory will need to be reinstalled in the current one